# Cropping a surface in python for Z values greater than

Tags: python, numpy, surface

So I've got a 3D surface plot of a function which represents some real data. Any values greater than 8.5 on the Z axis are a physical impossibility and therefore I would like to remove them from my plot. I've been struggling to do this, any help would be appreciated:

[image]

I want to set the values above 8 (most of the red) to NaN, but the plot appears to be empty when I try this. I've done some googling and discovered that surf plots do not like NaN's (apparently) and was wondering if anyone here could help!

The code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

X = np.arange(1.0,101.0,1.0) 
Y = np.arange(1.0,4.1, 0.04) 


X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

Z = ((0.3973473*(np.exp(np.log10(X)))) + 0.6176893) * Y

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                    linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do it with a fresh pair of eyes today:

```
qt = np.linspace(1.0, 100.0, num=100)
ic = np.linspace(1.0, 4.0, num=100)

qt, ic = np.meshgrid(qt, ic)

Z = ((0.3973473*(np.exp(np.log10(qt)))) + 0.6176893) * ic

for i in np.arange(len(qt)):
    for j in np.arange(len(ic)):
        if Z[j,i] > 8:
            Z[j,i] = np.nan
        else:
            pass


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(qt, ic, Z)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix the jagged lines on top?